# TexStudio inline preview problem

Tags: errors, texstudio, inline, miktex2.9, preview

I use texstudio as my editor and on one of my computer where I have reinstalled miketex and Texstudio, with the attached preview settings. But I get the following error message when doing inline preview (by highlighting text, right clicking and pressing "preview selection/parentheses"):

Process started: pdflatex.exe -interaction=nonstopmode -ini "&pdflatex hBRHSVD \dump"
Process started: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "HKCENV".tex
Process exited normally
Process exited with error(s)

No preview generated.[image: Texstudio Preview settings image]